# Traceback (most recent call last): _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with my code in Python

I want to transfer the data after entering it into the excel file

But I get an error with the title: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\yasen\Desktop\برمجة\graphics\main11.py", line 60, in 
firstname_text = Label(text = "الاسم الاول * ",).grid(row=0)
File "C:\Users\yasen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 2522, in grid_configure
self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack

my code

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd


def send_info():
  path = 'Registers.form.xlsx'
  df1 = pd.read_excel(path)
  SeriesA = df1['firstname']
  SeriesB = df1['secondname']
  SeriesC = df1['thirdname']
  SeriesD = df1['age']
  SeriesE = df1['phonenumber']
  SeriesF = df1['Departmentname']
  SeriesG = df1['familymembers']
  SeriesH = df1['bookingdate']
  A = pd.Series(firstname.get)
  B = pd.Series(secondname.get)
  C = pd.Series(thirdname.get)
  D = pd.Series(age.get)
  E = pd.Series(phonenumber.get)
  F = pd.Series(Departmentname.get)
  G = pd.Series(familymembers.get)
  H = pd.Series(bookingdate.get)
  SeriesA = SeriesA.append(A)
  SeriesB = SeriesA.append(B)
  SeriesC = SeriesA.append(C)
  SeriesD = SeriesA.append(D)
  SeriesE = SeriesA.append(E)
  SeriesF = SeriesA.append(F)
  SeriesG = SeriesA.append(G)
  SeriesH = SeriesA.append(H)
  df2 = pd.DataFrame({"firstname": SeriesA, "secondnamer": SeriesB, "thirdname": SeriesC, "age": SeriesD, "phonenumber": SeriesE, "Departmentname": SeriesF, "familymembers": SeriesG, "bookingdate": SeriesH})
  df2.to_excel(path, index=False)











  firstname_entry.delete(0, END)
  secondname_entry.delete(0, END)
  thirdname_entry.delete(0, END)
  age_entry.delete(0, END)
  phonenumber_entry.delete(0, END)
  Departmentname_entry.delete(0, END)
  familymembers_entry.delete(0, END)
  bookingdate_entry.delete(0, END)
  
screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("1080x1080")
screen.title("مديرية شؤون البطاقة الوطنية")
welcome_text = Label(text="أهلا وسهلا بكم في الحجز الالكتروني للبطاقة الموحدة ", fg="white", bg="green",height=2 ,width=1080)
welcome_text.pack()
 
firstname_text = Label(text = "الاسم الاول * ",).grid(row=0)
secondname_text = Label(text = "الاسم الثاني * ",).grid(row=1)
thirdname_text = Label(text = "الاسم الثالث * ",).grid(row=2)
age_text = Label(text = "العمر * ",).grid(row=3)
phonenumber_text = Label(text = "رقم الهاتف * ",).grid(row=4)
Departmentname_text = Label(text = "اسم دائرة الاحوال المدنية * ",).grid(row=5)
familymembers_text = Label(text = "عدد افراد الاسرة * ",).grid(row=6)
bookingdate_text = Label(text = "موعد تاريخ الحجز المطلوب * ",).grid(row=7)

firstname_text.place(x = 540, y = 70)
secondname_text.place(x = 540, y = 130)
thirdname_text.place(x = 540, y = 190)
age_text.place(x = 540, y = 250)
phonenumber_text.place(x = 540, y = 310)
Departmentname_text.place(x = 540, y = 370)
familymembers_text.place(x = 540, y = 430)
bookingdate_text.place(x = 540, y = 490)



firstname = StringVar()
secondname = StringVar()
thirdname = StringVar()
age = StringVar()
phonenumber = StringVar()
Departmentname = StringVar()
familymembers = StringVar()
bookingdate = StringVar()

firstname_entry = Entry(textvariable = firstname, width = "40")
secondname_entry = Entry(textvariable = secondname, width = "40")
thirdname_entry = Entry(textvariable = thirdname, width = "40")
age_entry = Entry(textvariable = age, width = "40")
phonenumber_entry = Entry(textvariable = phonenumber, width = "40")
Departmentname_entry = Entry(textvariable = Departmentname, width = "40")
familymembers_entry = Entry(textvariable = familymembers, width = "40")
bookingdate_entry = Entry(textvariable = bookingdate, width = "40")

firstname_entry.place(x = 450, y = 100)
secondname_entry.place(x = 450, y = 160)
thirdname_entry.place(x = 450, y = 220)
age_entry.place(x = 450, y = 280)
phonenumber_entry.place(x = 450, y = 340)
Departmentname_entry.place(x = 450, y = 400)
familymembers_entry.place(x = 450, y = 460)
bookingdate_entry.place(x = 450, y = 520)

firstname_entry.grid(row=0,column=1)
secondname_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)
thirdname_entry.grid(row=2,column=1)
age_entry.grid(row=3,column=1)
phonenumber_entry.grid(row=4,column=1)
Departmentname_entry.grid(row=5,column=1)
familymembers_entry.grid(row=6,column=1)
bookingdate_entry.grid(row=7,column=1)


register = Button(screen,text = "Register", width = "60", height = "2", command = send_info, bg = "grey").grid(row=3,column=1, pady=4)
register.place(x = 360, y = 600)

screen.mainloop ()
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is because Tkinter doesn't allow to use more than one placement of a widget in the whole script. So, if you want to run your code, then you'll have to remove either the `grid()` function everywhere and replace it with the `pack()` function or the remove the `pack()` function and replace it with the `grid()` function.

Comment: Thank you very much, the error is over
But another error occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\yasen\Desktop\Programming\graphics\main11.py", line 69, in <module>
     firstname_text.place(x = 540, y = 70)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'place'

Can you help me with it?

Comment: Sure.
`firstname_text = Label(text="الاسم الاول * ", ).grid(row=0)`
`firstname_text.place(x=540, y=70)`
Here, you have used `place()` and `grid()` functions on just one variable. So if you are wanting to move the Label, you'd have to doo it from another way because you can't use two placing methods for a single widget.

Comment: _"This is because Tkinter doesn't allow to use more than one placement of a widget in the whole script"_ - this is a false statement. You can use more then one in a script as a whole. In fact, I would argue that's a best practice. What you can't do is use more than one for children that share a common parent, which is what the error is telling the OP.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

As I just said on FB - you cant miy .place, .pack. and .grid

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
    
    
    def send_info():
        path = 'Registers.form.xlsx'
        df1 = pd.read_excel(path)
        SeriesA = df1['firstname']
        SeriesB = df1['secondname']
        SeriesC = df1['thirdname']
        SeriesD = df1['age']
        SeriesE = df1['phonenumber']
        SeriesF = df1['Departmentname']
        SeriesG = df1['familymembers']
        SeriesH = df1['bookingdate']
        A = pd.Series(firstname.get)
        B = pd.Series(secondname.get)
        C = pd.Series(thirdname.get)
        D = pd.Series(age.get)
        E = pd.Series(phonenumber.get)
        F = pd.Series(Departmentname.get)
        G = pd.Series(familymembers.get)
        H = pd.Series(bookingdate.get)
        SeriesA = SeriesA.append(A)
        SeriesB = SeriesA.append(B)
        SeriesC = SeriesA.append(C)
        SeriesD = SeriesA.append(D)
        SeriesE = SeriesA.append(E)
        SeriesF = SeriesA.append(F)
        SeriesG = SeriesA.append(G)
        SeriesH = SeriesA.append(H)
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(
            {"firstname": SeriesA, "secondnamer": SeriesB, "thirdname": SeriesC, "age": SeriesD, "phonenumber": SeriesE,
             "Departmentname": SeriesF, "familymembers": SeriesG, "bookingdate": SeriesH})
        df2.to_excel(path, index=False)
    
        firstname_entry.delete(0, END)
        secondname_entry.delete(0, END)
        thirdname_entry.delete(0, END)
        age_entry.delete(0, END)
        phonenumber_entry.delete(0, END)
        Departmentname_entry.delete(0, END)
        familymembers_entry.delete(0, END)
        bookingdate_entry.delete(0, END)
    
    
    screen = Tk()
    screen.geometry("1080x1080")
    screen.title("مديرية شؤون البطاقة الوطنية")
    welcome_text = Label(text="أهلا وسهلا بكم في الحجز الالكتروني للبطاقة الموحدة ", fg="white", bg="green", height=2,
                         width=1080)
    
    firstname_text = Label(text="الاسم الاول * ", )
    secondname_text = Label(text="الاسم الثاني * ", )
    thirdname_text = Label(text="الاسم الثالث * ", )
    age_text = Label(text="العمر * ", )
    phonenumber_text = Label(text="رقم الهاتف * ", )
    Departmentname_text = Label(text="اسم دائرة الاحوال المدنية * ", )
    familymembers_text = Label(text="عدد افراد الاسرة * ", )
    bookingdate_text = Label(text="موعد تاريخ الحجز المطلوب * ", )
    
    
    firstname = StringVar()
    firstname.set("Test")
    secondname = StringVar()
    thirdname = StringVar()
    age = StringVar()
    phonenumber = StringVar()
    Departmentname = StringVar()
    familymembers = StringVar()
    bookingdate = StringVar()
    
    firstname_entry = Entry(textvariable=firstname, width=40)
    secondname_entry = Entry(textvariable=secondname, width=40)
    thirdname_entry = Entry(textvariable=thirdname, width=40)
    age_entry = Entry(textvariable=age, width=40)
    phonenumber_entry = Entry(textvariable=phonenumber, width=40)
    Departmentname_entry = Entry(textvariable=Departmentname, width=40)
    familymembers_entry = Entry(textvariable=familymembers, width=40)
    bookingdate_entry = Entry(textvariable=bookingdate, width=40)
    
    firstname_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    secondname_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
    thirdname_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)
    age_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)
    phonenumber_entry.grid(row=4, column=1)
    Departmentname_entry.grid(row=5, column=1)
    familymembers_entry.grid(row=6, column=1)
    bookingdate_entry.grid(row=7, column=1)
    
    '''register = Button(screen, text="Register", width="60", height="2", command=send_info, bg="grey").grid(row=3, column=1,
                                                                                                          pady=4)
    register.place(x=360, y=600)'''
    
    screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want, like this.  You see `Label` on green background and gray button. I remove all widgets `grid()` because of that saying **cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack**

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd

def send_info():
    path = 'Registers.form.xlsx'
    df1 = pd.read_excel(path)
    SeriesA = df1['firstname']
    SeriesB = df1['secondname']
    SeriesC = df1['thirdname']
    SeriesD = df1['age']
    SeriesE = df1['phonenumber']
    SeriesF = df1['Departmentname']
    SeriesG = df1['familymembers']
    SeriesH = df1['bookingdate']
    A = pd.Series(firstname.get)
    B = pd.Series(secondname.get)
    C = pd.Series(thirdname.get)
    D = pd.Series(age.get)
    E = pd.Series(phonenumber.get)
    F = pd.Series(Departmentname.get)
    G = pd.Series(familymembers.get)
    H = pd.Series(bookingdate.get)
    SeriesA = SeriesA.append(A)
    SeriesB = SeriesA.append(B)
    SeriesC = SeriesA.append(C)
    SeriesD = SeriesA.append(D)
    SeriesE = SeriesA.append(E)
    SeriesF = SeriesA.append(F)
    SeriesG = SeriesA.append(G)
    SeriesH = SeriesA.append(H)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"firstname": SeriesA, "secondnamer": SeriesB, "thirdname": SeriesC, "age": SeriesD, "phonenumber": SeriesE, "Departmentname": SeriesF, "familymembers": SeriesG, "bookingdate": SeriesH})
    df2.to_excel(path, index=False)

    firstname_entry.delete(0, END)
    secondname_entry.delete(0, END)
    thirdname_entry.delete(0, END)
    age_entry.delete(0, END)
    phonenumber_entry.delete(0, END)
    Departmentname_entry.delete(0, END)
    familymembers_entry.delete(0, END)
    bookingdate_entry.delete(0, END)
  
screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("1080x1080")
screen.title("مديرية شؤون البطاقة الوطنية")
welcome_text = Label(text="أهلا وسهلا بكم في الحجز الالكتروني للبطاقة الموحدة ", fg="white", bg="green",height=2 ,width=1080)
welcome_text.pack()
 
firstname_text = Label(text="الاسم الاول * ")
secondname_text = Label(text="الاسم الثاني * ")
thirdname_text = Label(text="الاسم الثالث * ")
age_text = Label(text="العمر * ")
phonenumber_text = Label(text="رقم الهاتف * ")
Departmentname_text = Label(text="اسم دائرة الاحوال المدنية * ")
familymembers_text = Label(text="عدد افراد الاسرة * ")
bookingdate_text = Label(text="موعد تاريخ الحجز المطلوب * ")

firstname_text.place(x=540, y=70)
secondname_text.place(x=540, y=130)
thirdname_text.place(x=540, y=190)
age_text.place(x=540, y=250)
phonenumber_text.place(x=540, y=310)
Departmentname_text.place(x=540, y=370)
familymembers_text.place(x=540, y=430)
bookingdate_text.place(x=540, y=490)

firstname = StringVar()
secondname = StringVar()
thirdname = StringVar()
age = StringVar()
phonenumber = StringVar()
Departmentname = StringVar()
familymembers = StringVar()
bookingdate = StringVar()

firstname_entry = Entry(textvariable=firstname, width="40")
secondname_entry = Entry(textvariable=secondname, width="40")
thirdname_entry = Entry(textvariable=thirdname, width="40")
age_entry = Entry(textvariable=age, width="40")
phonenumber_entry = Entry(textvariable=phonenumber, width="40")
Departmentname_entry = Entry(textvariable=Departmentname, width="40")
familymembers_entry = Entry(textvariable=familymembers, width="40")
bookingdate_entry = Entry(textvariable=bookingdate, width="40")

firstname_entry.place(x=450, y=100)
secondname_entry.place(x=450, y=160)
thirdname_entry.place(x=450, y=220)
age_entry.place(x=450, y=280)
phonenumber_entry.place(x=450, y=340)
Departmentname_entry.place(x=450, y=400)
familymembers_entry.place(x=450, y=460)
bookingdate_entry.place(x= 450, y=520)

register = Button(screen,text="Register", width="60", height="2", command=send_info, bg="grey")
register.place(x=360, y=600)

screen.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]